# Filter array of objects by id and price range in a collection

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have a products table as shown below with a column `productPrice` and that contains an array of two objects the schema looks something like this:

[image]

Now in the product listing I'll get `rentalContractId` as `objectId` and a price range from max to min. Then I need to return only that specific product price falls between price range and `rentalContractId` is matching.

I been trying this query on product details collection.

```
db.products.aggregate([......, {
        "$match": {
            "productPrice": {
                "$elemMatch": {
                    "rentalContractId": ObjectId("64018dfc8a7d37f378d6c426"),
                    "price": {
                        "$lte": 9,
                        "$gte": 4           
                    }
                }
            },
        }
    }, .......]);
```

Can anyone please help me to understand this issue?

Entire query;

```
db.products.aggregate([
    {
        "$match": {
            "$and": [
                {
                    "isDeleted": false
                },
                {
                    "isArchived": false
                },
                {
                    "isProductDisplayAble": true
                },
                {
                    "createdBy": {
                        "$ne": "6469a515159d16142e64b68e"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bookings": {
                        "$not": {
                            "$elemMatch": {
                                "productBookingCompleteDate": {
                                    "$gte": "2023-05-21T04:59:01.105Z"
                                },
                                "productBookingStartDate": {
                                    "$lte": "2023-05-21T04:59:01.105Z"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$match": {
            "productTags": {
                "$in": [
                    "6456c1eb883d8e08841911ea"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    // here
    {
    $addFields: {
      productPrice: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$productPrice",
          cond: { $and: [ { $eq: [ "$$this.rentalContractId", ObjectId("64018dfc8a7d37f378d6c426") ] }, { $gte: [ "$$this.price", 4 ] }, { $lte: [ "$$this.price", 9 ] } ] }
        }
      }
    }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "rentalcontractdetails",
            "localField": "productPrice.rentalContractId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "rentalContract",
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$project": {
                        "contractType": 1
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "brands",
            "localField": "brandId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "brandId"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "dimensions",
            "localField": "productTags",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "dimensions"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "ratings",
            "localField": "_id",
            "foreignField": "productId",
            "as": "ratings"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "categoryones",
            "localField": "categoryOneId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "categoryOneId"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "categorytwos",
            "localField": "categoryTwoId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "categoryTwoId"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "categorythrees",
            "localField": "categoryThreeId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "categoryThreeId"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "shops",
            "localField": "shopId",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "shopId"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "users",
            "localField": "createdBy",
            "foreignField": "_id",
            "as": "createdBy"
        }
    },
    {
        "$lookup": {
            "from": "productcountschemas",
            "as": "selectedItemCount",
            "let": {
                "productId": "$_id"
            },
            "pipeline": [
                {
                    "$match": {
                        "$expr": {
                            "$and": [
                                {
                                    "$eq": [
                                        "$productId",
                                        "$$productId"
                                    ]
                                },
                                {
                                    "$eq": [
                                        "$createdBy",
                                        null
                                    ]
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "$project": {
            "_id": 1,
            "originalPrice": 1,
            "skuId": 1,
            "geoLocation": 1,
            "variantIdsArr": 1,
            "productWeight": 1,
            "packageDimensions": 1,
            "productRating": 1,
            "productSellerId": 1,
            "productTags": 1,
            "productColor": 1,
            "productPriceUnit": 1,
            "productMaterial": 1,
            "productSleeveType": 1,
            "productPatternType": 1,
            "productCareType": 1,
            "dressStyle": 1,
            "quantity": 1,
            "createdAt": 1,
            "isProductInStock": 1,
            "isProductVariationExists": 1,
            "stockAvailability": 1,
            "productImages": 1,
            "globalTradeItemNumber": 1,
            "launchDate": 1,
            "productBrief": 1,
            "productDescription": 1,
            "productLength": 1,
            "productLengthUnit": 1,
            "productNeckStyle": 1,
            "productSize": 1,
            "productSizeIndicator": 1,
            "productTitle": 1,
            "slug": 1,
            "targetGender": 1,
            "brandId._id": 1,
            "brandId.brandName": 1,
            "brandId.brandNameSlug": 1,
            "categoryOneId._id": 1,
            "categoryOneId.categoryName": 1,
            "categoryOneId.categoryNameSlug": 1,
            "categoryTwoId._id": 1,
            "categoryTwoId.categoryName": 1,
            "categoryTwoId.categoryNameSlug": 1,
            "categoryThreeId._id": 1,
            "categoryThreeId.categoryName": 1,
            "categoryThreeId.categoryNameSlug": 1,
            "shopId._id": 1,
            "shopId.shopName": 1,
            "createdBy._id": 1,
            "createdBy.companyName": 1,
            "createdBy.name": 1,
            "dimensions._id": 1,
            "dimensions.dimensionName": 1,
            "ratings._id": 1,
            "ratings.rating": 1,
            "rate": {
                "$avg": "$ratings.rating"
            },
            "ratedByPeople": {
                "$size": "$ratings"
            },
            "selectedItemCount": "$selectedItemCount.itemCount",
            "productPrice": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "$rentalContract",
                    "in": {
                        "$mergeObjects": [
                            {
                                "rentalContractId": "$$this._id"
                            },
                            {
                                "contractType": "$$this.contractType"
                            },
                            {
                                "price": {
                                    "$arrayElemAt": [
                                        "$productPrice.price",
                                        {
                                            "$indexOfArray": [
                                                "$productPrice.rentalContractId",
                                                "$$this._id"
                                            ]
                                        }
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "$skip": 0
    },
    {
        "$limit": 1
    },
    {
        "$sort": {
            "createdAt": -1
        }
    }
])
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the input document as code snippet? Meanwhile, you should use `$filter` to return the matched document in the array as projection.

Comment: can you also give an example document that should work. also do you get any result after 2nd match stage. if u create a mongoplayground demo then u can also view what the intermediate stages output. also are the object ids strings or ObjectId(..)